# Generic validation for Enum

Tags: c#, enums

What I'm trying to code:

```
public class Condition<TEnum>
{
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        return Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(this.Operator, true, out _);
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I got this compilation error with `Enum.TryParse` method:

> Error CS0453  The type 'TEnum' must be a non-nullable value type in
>   order to use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method
>   'Enum.TryParse(string, bool, out TEnum)'

I'm wondering How to implement generic enum validation properly?

Comment: You should use `class Condition<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria There´s no `Enum`-constraint.

Comment: @HimBromBeere unfortunately in `TryParse` declaration no.

Comment: Enum constraints exist in C# 7.3